# automount remote machine directrory

Tags: server, ssh, samba, automount

i have 2 ubuntu servers 22.04
i installed samba server on one of them (give it samba name with ip 192.168.3.10) and on the other (called access with ip 192.168.3.11) i used it to let the user logging
both ubuntu servers are joind the dc-win2016. i want to let the user to get their allowd shared directory from the samba server once they loging to the other ubuntu server
so once the doamin user ssh to 192.168.3.11 will retrive the shared directory that allow to access from samba server 192.168.3.10.
that need automout or ?
i need help and the steps to do this please